# Java crypto without Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files

Tags: java, jce

I have previously experienced a lot of trouble with JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files. I never want to have to install one again. I want to write Java crypto which "just works".

Are there any options for crypto without USJPFs, or am I better off just changing to a different language? (I already know C, Python, JS and a little Rust.)

Iirc, even Bouncy Castle suffered from needing USJPF.

Comment: @Henry Thanks, answer and I'll accept it.  Also: https://golb.hplar.ch/2017/10/JCE-policy-changes-in-Java-SE-8u151-and-8u152.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle Java 8u162 on the Java cryptography is no longer restricted. See https://golb.hplar.ch/2017/10/JCE-policy-changes-in-Java-SE-8u151-and-8u152.html